# Include two modules inside an AAR in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I have the following project structure for my library, where `lib1` depends on `lib2`:

```
/
/lib1/
/lib1/build.gradle
/lib2/
/lib2/build.gradle
/build.gradle
/settings.gradle
```

I am building an `aar` file of `lib1` that I can distribute. Before I added the `lib2` dependency, it works fine. But now I get a `VerifyError` when I try to run an application that uses my `aar`.

Neither `lib1` nor `lib2` are available on maven or some other places.

Is it possible to include `lib2` inside the `lib1` `aar`?

Comment: have you looked into transitive dependency ?

Comment: Does it work with aar generation, when I'm not using any Maven repository to publish my library? I can't test because I change the structure of the library.

Answer (score 1):

If you review the AAR Format spec you will see there is a location for lib jars to be placed.

From the [Android Tools](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format) site.

> The 'aar' bundle is the binary distribution of an Android Library
> Project.
>
> The file extension is .aar, and the maven artifact type should be aar
> as well, but the file itself a simple zip file with the following
> entries:
>
> ```
>  /AndroidManifest.xml (mandatory) 
>  /classes.jar (mandatory)
>  /res/ (mandatory) 
>  /R.txt (mandatory) 
>  /assets/ (optional)
>  /libs/*.jar (optional)
>  /jni/<abi>/*.so (optional)
>  /proguard.txt (optional)
>  /lint.jar (optional)
> ```
>
> These entries are directly at the root of the zip file.
>
> The R.txt file is the output of aapt with --output-text-symbols.

If you can package `lib2` as a jar file you can place it at `/libs/lib2.jar` in your resulting `lib1.aar` file. It may be worth trying to just put the AAR inside the `/libs` directory though the android gradle plugin may not handle this natively. If so you can do some custom gradle task to unpack it and place it in the correct place at build time.

Either way this is non standard behavior and it would be best to package and deliver both separately.